# Como diversos programas conseguem fazer o download do XML da NF-e brasileira?

Tags: php, xml, nfe

vejo que muitos sites e sistemas oferecem serviço de Download do XML emitidos por contribuintes brasileiros.

Alguém tem conhecimento se existe além da nota Técnica "002/2012" que estabelece um *WebServices* para download mediante eventos, porém o prazo é de 180 dias após a emissão e dentre outras restrições.

Acredito que esses sistemas tem uma forma, claro, de burlar o Captcha do site da Receita e ter acesso aos arquivos. Tem ferramentas inclusive, que usam certificado digital para baixar o XML "original" emitido.

http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=

Alguém tem conhecimento de uma forma "legal" ou uma recomendação da Receita de como fazer o download desse documento?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Acredito que a única forma legal de se fazer isso seja através dos Web Services da Receita Federal disponibilizados no [Portal da Nota Fiscal Eletrônica - Web Services](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/webServices.aspx?tipoConteudo=Wak0FwB7dKs=).

Atualmente estou trabalhando em um sistema de NF-e, já faço tanto o envio de informações como o recebimento (inclusive do XML da NF-e) através dos Web Services, porém para todas as operações feitas de forma legal, precisa dos dados do certificado digital do emissor ou destinatário.

Sem o certificado digital que pode ser tanto do tipo A1 como do tipo A3, não há como realizar a conexão com os servidores da Receita. Se existe outra forma legal, eu desconheço e a Receita Federal também não mencionou isto em suas Notas Técnicas.

A única forma legal de se fazer isso é utilizando os Web Services da Receita Federal, realizando a autenticação com o certificado digital do usuário.

Comment: Qual seria o WebService para download da NF-e utilizando o Certificado Digital da Empresa que está recebendo a NF-e ?

Answer (score 4):

A forma legal de se fazer isso é usando a comunicação direta com a API da Receita.
Essa comunicação é feita por webservices.

O site da nfephp permite que você implemente isso por conta própria:
http://www.nfephp.org/pt/latest/

Caso você não tenha domínio em programação, pode usar a Focus NFe API.
Mas não é gratuito, no entanto permite que você obtenha tanto o XML quanto o PDF da DANFE de maneira bem prática:
https://focusnfe.com.br/api/doc/nfe/

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é durante a emissão (autorização), adicionar uma tag específica autorizando Cnpjs a baixar o XML.

Isso requer autorização pelo menos verbal do emissor.

Um exemplo é a Admsis, que tem um erp 100% web.

O emissor autoriza o Cnpj da Admsis a baixar o XML via web services ou no site da sefaz nacional.

A sefaz estadual pode não permitir isso, como é o caso de SP.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, existe um software chamado **Auxílio NF-e** que baixa o XML de NF-e, CT-e, NFC-e sem e com certificado digital. Tem opção também de baixar com e sem a manifestação do destinatário o XML original.
Caso precise, eles oferecem integração com seu sistema.
Site: [www.auxilionfe.com](http://www.auxilionfe.com)